# Is there a whatsapp client for linux desktop?

Tags: instant-messaging, whatsapp

Ideally, I would like something like http://web.telegram.org for WhatsApp.

But I'm just looking for a way to receive and send messages from my Ubuntu Desktop.

Is there some client or any other way to achieve that?

Comment: Whatsapp is specifically designed to be bound to your phone device. If you want to use messaging from other devices look at alternatives like Telegram, Google Hangouts... (just examples!). Then convince your friends to migrate as well. Personally I have no idea why people are still using Whatsapp having limitations like these. The apps for Windows I saw sometime is really one big hack. Either it's an Android simulator or a reverse engineered implementation of the protocol which can break any time. Also, you won't be able to use multiple devices with the same number...

Comment: @opensas, yes, https://web.whatsapp.com/

Answer (score 4):

WhatsApp doesn't have an open API. Some open source projects have reverse-engineered the protocol, but they still need a client token which WhatsApp doesn't give out to 3rd parties.